# what is the minimum sample size to train RNN to do embedding?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, word-embeddings

I have about 1600 sequences, each 35 data points long (Its actually multivariate, so each data point is a vector). is this sufficient to train an RNN (LSTM) to do embedding?

Comment: Theres no way to answer this. It depends completely on the problem being solved, and the noise in the data.

Comment: Can you think of an optimistic scenario where this can give reasonable results?